# Simplifying Boolean Expressions with DeMorgan’s law

Tags: boolean-expression, demorgans-law

I need help simplifying the following Boolean expressions using DeMorgan’s law:

a) `[ (AB)' + (CD)' ]'`

and

b) `[(X+Y)' + (X+Y') ]'`

Please show some steps so I can do the other ones myself

Comment: What have you tried? What rules do you know that you could apply to these problems?

Comment: I know the simple rules: [A+B]'=A'B', [AB]'=A'+B' etc... Just got stuck in a new one: [(X+Y)' + (XY') ]'

Answer (score 2):

**a)**
First step is the outermost negation: distribute it.

```
((AB)')'*((CD)')'
```

You see we have double negations which means the expression itself. (p')' = p
therefore

```
ABCD

[ (AB)' + (CD)' ]'  --> ABCD
```

**b)**

Distribute the outermost negation:

```
((X+Y)')'(X+Y')'
```

get rid of the double negation:

```
(X+Y)(X+Y')'
```

again, distribute the negation (the one at the outer part of the expression):

```
(X+Y)(X'Y)
```

When you distribute (X+Y), we get

```
XX'Y + YX'Y
```

Since there is XX' in the first part of disjunction, the expression XX'Y equals to 0 (False).
Multiple instances of the same thing in an expression is the same thing itself. ppp = p.
Therefore:
    0 + YX' --> YX'

```
[ (X+Y)' + (X+Y') ]' --> YX'
```

Im sorry for non-formal language:) hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to do this [(X+Y)' + (XY') ]' and I got X'Y' . Could you please double check if it's ok?

Comment: I think the answer is right. Also tried it from an [online De Morgan Calculator](http://joshtam.net/world/bee-calc.html). You can check it as well, just type `!(!(a+b) + (a+ !b))` for expression and you'll get a truth table. About your answer, could you double check the `(X+Y')'` negation again? Perhaps you might have missed the negation of Y.

Answer (score 1):

Steps are included:

a: [ (AB)' + (CD)' ]' = (AB)'' * (CD)'' = (AB) * (CD) = ABCD

b: [ (X+Y)' + (X+Y') ]' = (X+Y)'' * (X+Y')' = (X+Y) * (X'*Y) .. Simplifying this further relies on the distributive property.

Comment: Thank you. Could you verify that [(X+Y)' + (XY') ]' = X'Y?